# Equivalent of CSS adjacent selector in LaTeX

Tags: conditionals, css

In CSS you can use the adjacent selector to create conditional formatting. For example, p + p to format a paragraph that follows a paragraph, or h1 + p to format a paragraph that follows a h1 element. Is there an equivalent in LaTeX?

Comment: And what kind of "formatting" do you want to do to a paragraph following another/heading?

Comment: Change the before paragraph and indentation.

Comment: It's difficult to think og LaTeX in terms of the CSS model, so it's probably better to rephrase the question to include 1) exactly what you want to achieve, and 2) a MWE that shows what you've done so far.