# Conditional spacing based on length of chapter title

Tags: spacing, sectioning, vertical-alignment, chapters, conditionals

In LaTeX, (or possibly XeLaTeX), how can one achieve the following:

- A double spacing a 1- or 2-line chapter title, and single spacing under a 3- or more-line chapter title.
- A triple space underneath titles, unless immediately followed by a `\section` command, in which case it takes a double space

I am using the report document class. What is the best strategy to achieve flexibility for the following scenarios:

1. Line spacing: single space for `\chapter` that have three lines
2. Line spacing: double space for `\chapter` that have two lines
3. Paragraph spacing: triple space between `\chapter` or `\section` and body text
4. Paragraph spacing: double space between `\chapter` and `\section`

Comment: This is similar to [a question I asked long time ago][1]. I hope you find an answer.


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124772/equivalent-of-css-adjacent-selector-in-latex

Comment: @Amaru Well, (1) Your question seems to be yet a bit different, but (2) It's difficult to judge how much since it's lacking a MWE.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Please: by "double spaced" you mean that the lines of the chapter title should be far away of each other (that's the standard meaning) or that there should be a gap below the chapter title?

Comment: 1. I am using the report document class with bib latex. The MWE (Minimal Working Example) asked for may not be useful in this case, since line spacing and paragraph spacing (space below and above) for title (\chapter) and subtitle (\section) are not given in the main tex file. The question has to do with adjustments that need to be made in other files such as cls or sty that will reflect on the main tex file. 

2. @tohecz By double space I mean the equivalent of two blank/line spaces, which applies to both lines of chapter titles and gaps below it.

Comment: Is there any news here? Please add a minimal working example.